# If $ b_{n}=2+\frac{1}{b_{n-1}} , \ \ b_{0}=2$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n=1+\sqrt 2 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, continued-fractions

If $ b_{n}=2+\frac{1}{b_{n-1}} , \ \ b_{0}=2$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{n}=1+\sqrt 2 $ , then find $ \ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{b_{n+1}-(1+\sqrt 2)}{b_n-(1+\sqrt 2)}\right| $ .

**Answer:** I think $ \ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{b_{n+1}-(1+\sqrt 2)}{b_n-(1+\sqrt 2)}\right| =1$.  So the order of convergence $=1$.

**Am I right ? Any help is there ?**

Comment: is $p_n$ equal to $b_n$?

Comment: yes my mistake it is $ b_{n} $

Comment: Where is your input to this question?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{b_{n+1}-(1+\sqrt{2})}{b_{n}-(1+\sqrt{2})} \right| &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{2+\frac{1}{b_n}-(1+\sqrt{2})}{b_{n}-(1+\sqrt{2})} \right| \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{b_n}\left| \frac{(1-\sqrt{2})b_n+1}{b_{n}-(1+\sqrt{2})} \right|
\\&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{b_n}\left| \frac{b_n+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}}}{b_{n}-(1+\sqrt{2})} \right|
\\&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{b_n}\left| \frac{b_n-(1+\sqrt{2})}{b_{n}-(1+\sqrt{2})} \right|
\\&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{b_n}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Write $c_n=b_n-(1+\sqrt2)$.
Then
$$b_{n+1}=2+\frac1{1+\sqrt2+c_n}
=2+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt2}\left(1-\frac{c_n}{1+\sqrt2}+O(c_n^2)\right)
=1+\sqrt2-\frac{c_n}{(1+\sqrt2)^2}+O(c_n^2)$$
etc.

Comment: so what is the order of convergence ?

Comment: Looks linear with each $c_n$ getting smaller by a factor of $(1+\sqrt{2})^2 = 3+2\sqrt{2}$.